# Error al enviar imagen en whatsappweb js

Tags: nodejs, javascript-metodo

Al intentar enviar una imagen con la libreria whatsappweb.js no envia nada este es mi codigo

```
let chatID = CODIGO_PAIS + req.body.telefono + "@c.us";
        // Enviar la imagen al chat
        cliente.sendMessage(chatID, {
            body: req.body.mensaje,
            mimetype: 'image/png',
            caption: '¡Hola! Esta es una imagen en base64'
        }).then(() => {
            console.log('Imagen en base64 enviada correctamente');
            res.status(200).json('Todo corecto');
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error al enviar la imagen en base64:', error);
            res.status(400).json('Envio incorrecto');
        });
```

Dice que se envio la imagen correctamente pero no envia nada